# Why are accessor methods defined within the main class?

Tags: java, procedural-programming

I am currently studying Java for my procedural programming module. I've read that in procedural programming, records must be defined outside the main class but that the accessor methods for these records must be defined within the main class.

An example is shown below:

```
class person // Record definition
{
    String name;
    int age;
}

class personalDetails // Main class
{
    public static void main (String [] a)
    { 
        mainMethod(); 
        System.exit(0);
    } 

    
    public static void mainMethod()
    {
        // Main method
    } 
    
    // Getter method to get name
    public static String getName(person p)
    {
        return p.name;
    }

    // Getter method to get age
    public static int getAge(person p)
    {
        return p.age;
    }

    // Setter method to set name
    public static void setName(person p, String name)
    {
        p.name = name;
    }

    // Setter method to set age
    public static void setAge(person p, int age)
    {
        p.age = age;
    }
}
```

Why is this necessary?

I know that we cannot define the accessor methods within the definition of the record as this is an OOP approach but I don't fully understand why can't we define the record within the main class where the accessor methods are.

Comment: I have to say choosing Java for a course on procedural programming is a weird choice. But if that's what they did, then the answer to your question is simple: they don't do what you suggest because that would be OOP and not procedural. The closes you can get to procedural programming in Java is what you show: classes without any code with only fields and static methods to manipulate them.

Comment: "I've read that in procedural programming, records must be defined outside the main class..." You don't have classes in procedural programming.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but why is it OOP style if we define the record within the main class? What's the difference in having it outside?

Comment: I don't think it is "OOP style" to do so: define the class where it is most appropriate. But, consider, a main class is like the driver of a car: they cause the car to move; the main class "drives" the other code. You don't build the car inside the driver, though.

Comment: "*why can't we define the record within the main class where the accessor methods are*". You could. It should be declared static though, otherwise Java will implicitly capture a reference to the enclosing class. Again, that's an example of why choosing Java for procedural code is really a square peg, round hole. Its defaults are geared around the expectation that you'll be using OOP. A procedural language should really at the very least have the concept of free functions.

Answer (score 0):

In "traditional" procedural programming code and the data it operates on are quite separate: You have data structures that don't have any code assigned to it and you have code that doesn't have the ability to store code.

In Java the two are co-mingled: all code and all data has some relation to classes (I'm including interfaces, enums and records in this definition as well, the distinction is not important for this): methods are part of a class and fields belong to classes as well.

So in the normal Java style you'd define the fields of a type together with methods that act on it:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int age;

    // omitting constructors

    public String getDescription() {
      return name + " is " + age + " years old.";
    }

}
```

Here you clearly combine both the data (the fields `name` and `age`) and the code (the method `getDescription`) into a single unit.

In procedural programming those two things would be separate (I'm using a Java-style syntax here, but that exact code I show is not valid Java).

```
type Person {
  String name;
  int age;
}

String getDescription(Person p) {
  return p.name + " is " + p.age + " years old.";
}
```

Methods that are not in any type are not possible in Java, so to get close to this, you'll have to put it into a class (any class really):

```
class Person {
  String name;
  int age;
}

class PersonMethods {
  static String getDescription(Person p) {
    return p.name + " is " + p.age + " years old.";
  }
}
```

Note also that I made the method `static` indicating that it doesn't act on an instance of `PersonMethods`. This is another indication that we're using Java to implement a programming model that it's not meant to implement.

Where exactly those methods are doesn't really matter. In theory you could even put them in `Person` itself and keep them `static` with a `Person p` parameter, but that would probably look too much like regular OOP.